# Learning Swift functions and getting wrong output

Tags: swift, function

[image: mycode1]
[image: mycode]

I am doing a homework assignment, learning how to use functions.
I have created a function. and my output is coming out as (function) 
and not as what it should be ("Stuff")

I'm more then positive my code is written correctly but my output is 
not coming out as the result I need but as (function) not sure what else to try

```
func printsStuff() {
    prints("Stuff")
}
print(printsStuff)
```

My output is "function" instead of "stuff"

Comment: You have to *call* the function: `printsStuff()`

Comment: i just changed it and my result is still just "function" instead of "stuff"

Comment: I doubt that. Please [edit] your question and show the actual code (as text, not as screenshots). Your posted code does not even compile.

Comment: i have added two pictures to show what im doing and one with the suggested correction

Comment: The suggestion was to replace `print(printsStuff)` by `printsStuff()`. I cannot see that anywhere in your code.

Comment: ok i misunderstood. i just renamed the actual function.

Comment: thank you was very helpful im just learning xcode now and the smallest things like this get me stuck for a long time. i really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please, do not post pictures of code or pictures of text output. Copy and paste your code and copy and paste the output, as text, into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you dont have the understanding of functions.
Watch the definition:

```
func name()
{
    dosomething
}
```

So - when you would like to create a function which print something out try this:

```
func myPrint()
{
    print("my print is correct!")
}
```

Now you created a function. But this function is never used.

That's why you call your function with

```
myPrint()
```

Output should be:

```
"my print is correct!"
```

Right at this moment you say to Swift "Hey buddy, here is something. Can you print out what something is?"
And Swift told you "hey buddy - its a function".

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're trying to do is return "stuff" from printStuff, then print that instead?

```
func printsStuff() -> String{
    return "Stuff"
}
print(printsStuff())
```

That should print "Stuff" instead of printsStuff.

Or if you just want to call a function which does the printing rather than return a string you can do this

```
func printsStuff(){
    print("Stuff")
}
printsStuff()
```

Have a look at [Functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) documentation for Swift.

Comment: yes this works great. thank you very much! i really appreciate your help!

Comment: @dreezy216 Here we thank by accepting the answer if it was helpful.